# Transitioning between two activities using slider in android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-layout

I am creating a friend finding app in Android Studio 1.1.0 which incorporates the Google Maps API. This does not allow me to create any widgets on my current activity so I would like to create a slider (Similar to Facebook app on IOS) in which data can be displayed.

Examples:

[image]
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please post a gif or a picture of that feature from the Facebook app on IOS then we'll figure out a way to help

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/la2nuhw5lqil17e/AADAOBGgHqlP_rHmtbCzPOsFa?dl=0

Comment: Theres a dropbox link to two pictures

Comment: You can visit [this official Android documentation page](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) about creating a navigation drawer. Or [this tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/add-navigation-drawer-android) about adding a navigation drawer.